# Translation of Radak's commentary

Tags: commentaries, translation

I am still learning Hebrew, so some aid in translating this short passage would be much appreciated. Seems to say something about the Babylonian exile and regarding *kere* and *ketiv*?

Radak's commentary on [II Samuel 15:21](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.15.21?lang=bi&with=Radak&lang2=en):

> כי אם במקום. אם כתיב ולא קרי והענין אחד אם קרי או לא קרי והמלות האלה דכתיבין ולא קורין או דקורין ולא כתיבין וכן קרי וכתיב נראה כי בגלות הראשון אבדו הספרים ונטלטלו והחכמים יודעי המקרא מתו ואנשי כנסת הגדולה שהחזירו התורה ליושנה מצאו מחלוקת בספרים הנמצאים והלכו בהם אחר הרוב לפי דעתם ובמקום שלא השיגה דעתם על הברור כתבו האחד ולא נקדו או כתבו מבחוץ ולא כתבו מבפנים או כתבו אחד מבחוץ ואחד מבפנים:

Could a full translation be provided please

Comment: It basically says that the "אם" is written but not read, and he speculates that these differences are because after the first exile the books were lost, and there were no _Chakhamim_ left who knew their correct version. So when they re-wrote the books, they marked where they were doubtful as to the wording, they either put the word in to be written but not read, or to be read but not written, or to be read differently than written.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the Radak's view is not generally accepted. Usually when he writes this, Minchas Shai makes a point to argue.

Comment: Even if his view isn't accepted, it would be nice to see his perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my loose translation:

> כי אם במקום. אם כתיב ולא קרי והענין אחד אם קרי או לא קרי והמלות האלה דכתיבין ולא קורין או דקורין ולא כתיבין וכן קרי וכתיב נראה כי בגלות הראשון אבדו הספרים ונטלטלו והחכמים יודעי המקרא מתו ואנשי כנסת הגדולה שהחזירו התורה ליושנה מצאו מחלוקת בספרים הנמצאים והלכו בהם אחר הרוב לפי דעתם ובמקום שלא השיגה דעתם על הברור כתבו האחד ולא נקדו או כתבו מבחוץ ולא כתבו מבפנים או כתבו אחד מבחוץ ואחד מבפנים:

> [The word] "Im" is written and not read, but the matter is [the same], whether it is read or not read. These words which are written and not read or read and not written, and so too, [when words are] written and read [differently], it seems that in the first exile, they lost the books [of Tanach] and they were moved around, and the scholars who knew the [precise wording] of scripture died, and the Men of the Great Assembly, who returned the crown to its glory, found disagreements in some of the [remaining/discovered] books, and they followed what they considered to be the majority [text]. In places where they weren't certain of the correct reading, they wrote one [of the versions] and did not vowelize it, or they wrote it in the margins but not in the actual body of the text, or they wrote one version in the margin and another in the body of the text.